# How do I count the number of items > 0 in a Dictionary<string, int> using Linq in C#/.Net?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Hi I have a dictionary defined as:

```
Dictionary<string, int> sampleDictionary;
```

I would like to be able to do the following:

1) Select a list of values where the item is > 0

I've tried using sampleDictionary.SelectMany() and sampleDictionary.Select(),
but I can't quite seem to get the syntax right.

Can someone please help get me pointed in the right direction?

Thanks,
JohnB

Comment: what do you mean by list of values

Comment: If you want to filter you need to use `Where` first.  Then you can use `Select` to choice either the key or the value.  Right now I'm not sure which one you want.

Comment: If you just want the int values, begin your linq with `sampleDictionary.Values`. Do you just want the int values, or do you want the string keys associated with them as well?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Thanks, I finally figured it out: sampleDictionary.Where(item => item.Value > 1)

Comment: @JohnB in your question you specifically ask:`"1) Select a list of values where the item is > 0"`, but then you say `sampleDictionary.Where(item => item.Value > 1) ` solved your problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of approaches.

One is to get the Values property of the dictionary, and then perform your linq operations on that.

```
sampleDictionary.Values.Where(...).Select(...)
```

The other is to use the `value` property of each key-value pair

```
sampleDictionary.Where(x => x.Value > 0).Select(x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this method.

```
foreach(int i in sampleDictionary.Values)
{

    if(i > 0)
    {
      //...
    }    

}
```

Comment: The question specifically asks how to do it with Linq...

Answer (score 0):

hope this help.

You can do it using the query syntax. I think it is easier to understand if you're not familiar with Linq.

Dim sampleDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

```
Dim countZero = (From item In sampleDictionary  
                 Where item.Value > 0  
                 Select item).Count
```

you also can use the lambda style if you want shorter syntax

Answer (score 0):

This code will count the number of items with a value greater than zero.

```
var result = (from x in sampleDictionary.Values where x > 0 select x).Count();
```